# Which transitive verbs can form notional passives?

Tags: verbs, passive-voice

Could someone please tell me which transitive verbs can form notional passives? I only know that they are usually formed with intransitive active verbs.

Comment: Think it might help to explain what you mean by "notional passive"?

Answer (score 6):

A **notional passive** is an *active*, normally transitive verb that is used with a *passive* 'meaning'. It is not an actual passive verb, but it resembles one. In general, there is no limit to which transitive verbs can be used with a notional passive; in many cases, you could apply it to new verbs. It does look informal with verbs that are not commonly used this way.

> - People read this sentence without effort.
> - This sentence is read without effort. —
>     *[passive]*
> - This sentence reads well. — *[active, but
>     notional passive]*

It could be defined as a verb that is *syntactically active* but has its *subject* in the *[semantic role](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_relation) of a patient*—or any other role normally occupied by the *object* of the verb when it is active.

Comment: Crikey.  That was an erudite answer!  **applause**

Comment: @JoeBlow: Hah, thanks! Actually I had to Google it...

Comment: Is there any difference between "notional passive" and "ergative"? Sounds a bit of a wishy-washy term unless I'm missing something...

Comment: @NeilCofey: I was trying to think of *ergative*, but it refused to come up. I think at least the terms overlap to a large extent. But frankly I have always found *ergative* ill chosen, because it is terribly unintuitive. A "working" verb—I'm always forced to look it up. *Notational passive* is quite clear, by contrast. By the way, I think *ergative* was invented for other languages than English and is mainly used to describe the *ergative case*. In other words, I generally wouldn't touch that word with a long pole. But you may be right.

Comment: "ergative" is reasonably common as a term to describe English, though I admit it's an unintuitive word. Maybe something like "passivoid" would have been better. One problem also with the term/notion is that there's sometimes a blurred line between "unaccusative" and "ergative".